# Accessing a Private Constructor from Outside the Class in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, visibility, default-constructor

If I define a class with a private default constructor and a public constructor that has parameters, how can I access the private constructor?

```
public class Bob
{
   public String Surname { get; set; }

   private Bob()
   { }

   public Bob(string surname)
   {
      Surname = surname;
   }
}
```

I can access the private constructor via a static method on the class like this:

```
public static Bob GetBob()
{
   return new Bob();
}
```

I thought that I could access the private constructor via an extension method, since (according to my understanding) extension methods are translated so that they ***appear to be*** static methods on the class, but I can't:

```
static class Fred
{
   public static Bob Bobby(this Bob bob)
   {
      return new Bob();
   }
}
```

So, how can I access the private constructor?

Thank you

---

## EDIT:

The reason that I wanted to do this was that I wanted to create tests for one of our business classes, but not allow a consumer of this class to be able to instantiate an object incorrectly. I'm testing it, so I know (I hope!) under what circumstances the tests will fail. I'm still a testing n00b right now so my idea may or may not have been the "wrong way" of doing things.

I've changed my testing strategy to just do things the way the a consumer of this class would, i.e. calling the public methods and if the public methods are OK, assuming that the private methods are OK. I would still prefer to test the private methods, but my boss *is* breathing down my neck on a deliverable :-(

Comment: Humor me, Why would you want to invoke your private contructor outside your class implementation ?

Comment: Why the close vote? It's still a valid question, even if it's not recommended to get the constructor.

Comment: Agreed -- still a valid question, why close?

Comment: Re: Testing private methods.  I have found that by testing private methods individually, my tests are smaller and more precise than if I test only public methods.  I tend to make 'private' into 'protected' and write a specific wrapper class in the test library to expose them as public versions rather than use reflection.

Comment: @Dr Herbi, Your class most likely have some code smells if your test methods get big to be able to test private/protected methods.

Comment: Yes -- lots of legacy code written by previous devs.  Plus I have to say that the business logic involved (part-exchange sales) is _ridiculously_ complicated (more complex than my PhD for a start) -- but that's how our customers work.

Comment: I can hardly imagine a reason for a private ctor. Ok, object pool pattern and get instance, but even there i would make it protected. So, is there any reason for a private ctor at all?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## New answer (nine years later)

There is now several overloads for [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Boolean_) that allow you to use non public constructors:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourClass), true);
```

`true` = use non public constructors.

.

## Old answer

***Default constructors are private for a reason. The developer doesn't make it private for fun.***

But if you still want to use the default constructor you get it by using reflection.

```
var constructor = typeof(Bob).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null);
var instance = (Bob)constructor.Invoke(null);
```

**Edit**

I saw your comment about testing. Never test protected or private methods / properties. You have probably done something wrong if you can't manage to test those methods/properties through the public API. Either remove them or refactor the class.

**Edit 2**

Forgot a binding flag.

Comment: Isn't this a sort of a hack? To bypass the reason for making the constructor private?

Comment: Yes it is. That's why I wrote *Default constructors are private for a reason. The developer doesn't make it private for fun.*

Comment: Thanks. However, the `GetConstructor` method returns null, so that code throws a NullReferenceException. `typeof(Bob).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic);` returns an empty array.

Comment: Try again with the updated code. I just tested it myself and it works.

Comment: @Liviu M. - Yup, this is clearly a hack, but that is exactly what the OP asks for in his question, so that makes this the correct answer ;)

Comment: "never test protected or private methods" - If the code you are looking at is NOT under test, then you most certainly should place tests around protected and private methods BEFORE you start refactoring to make them obsolete... If its not under test, then its not refactoring.. its just changing shit

Comment: If you can't get good code coverage in the private methods through testing the public methods you have dead code that should be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure about the comment "never test private  methods". While I generally agree, what if he wants to MOCK this class to test in isolation an object that uses an instance of this class? He may want to keep the method private because it's created by an utility static method, but wants to mock it. Or, more easily, the api is badly written but you still want to have tests for your code dealong with the api, I had a situation like that

Comment: I found this very useful for my needs, so I want to give an argument for where it **is** appropriate to do hacky reflection like this: locked away in the basement of a very well-tested, reusable library.  This trick allowed me to use immutable objects with EntityFramework by a behind-the-scenes transformation of `o => new MyImmutableObject(o.Name, o.Description)` to `o => new MyImmutableObject() { o.Name, o.Description}`, without having to sacrifice immutability elsewhere (the default constructor is private).  Thank you for warning against it, but thank you doubly for answering anyway.

Comment: I *disagree* about not testing private methods.  Here is a situation in which I think it's appropriate.  Suppose that you have a constructor that takes an array.  It calls a private function in a loop with each element of the array.  I wouldn't make the private function public just to test it.

Comment: I wrote that five years ago. However, in your case another solution is to not have that in a constructor (or a private method), but in a new class which generates the result that the mentioned class want to work with. My point is that every time you have a private method that can't be reached easily, you might have to rethink your design.  Private methods that is hard to test ***is*** a potential smell and should always be evaluated a second time.

Comment: I often find myself using reflection on private constructors and fields in order to mock classes that are strongly bound to static instances of other classes. Within legacy-code you often can´t apply dependency-injection everywhere so you have to provide the dependencies in some way. Doing this via reflection to avoid the *actual* instantiation of the dependency with a high chance to fail is hacky but gets rid of those dependencies for testing-purposes.

Comment: often you want to also add BindingFlags.Public to get any ctor

Comment: @kofifus In this case it was about private constructors. Hence the NonPublic flag.

Comment: This answer is terribly out of date. You should probably be using one of the [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41793861/3198973) methods.

Comment: @RubberDuck Answers that are 9 years old tend to be out of date ;)

Comment: For constructors with parameters, just replace new Type[0] with the list of corresponding types of the parameters (ex: new[] { typeof(string) })

Comment: *chuckle* Thanks @jgauffin!! "New answer (nine years later)" Thanks for having the integrity (and memory!) to update your answer to help people who will come and look at this and will now not see outdated information. :-)

Comment: @jgauffin .............. stupid tagging thing not stupid tagging. *shouts at clouds *

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways around this issue:

*One*:  Make the constructor public.  If you need to access it from outside the class why is it private (it might be that you only want to access the private constructor for testing, in which case this is a valid issue).

*Two*: Make the constructor protected, then access it through a derived class:

```
public class Bob
{
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    protected Bob()
    { }

    public Bob(string surname)
    {
        Surname = surname;
    }
}

public class Fred : Bob
{
    public Fred()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

*Three*: Use reflection (as shown by jgauffin).

Comment: As you can see in the edit on the question, it is for testing, thanks. And the formatting is still out.

Comment: the code formatting bugs when using lists in the same answer.

Comment: Cheers -- I'll try and remember that for the future.

Comment: If you want to allow access within your library you can make the constructor internal.

Answer (score 2):

In additional to @jgauffin's answer which tells how to call private constructors via reflection:

**Is it possible to change the modifiers of the private constructor?**

It seems that you are implementing Factory Pattern in your code. Thus the modifier is supposed to be `internal`.

```
public class Product
{
   //others can't create instances directly outside the assembly
   internal Product() { }    
}
public class ProductProvider
{
   //they can only get standardized products by the provider
   //while you have full control to Product class inside ProductProvider
   public static Product CreateProduct()
   {
       Product p = new Product();    
       //standardize the product
       return p;
   }  
}
```

**Extension methods**

```
public static MyExt
{
   public static void DoSomething(this Product p) { }
}
```

Calling `p.DoSomething()` actually equals to `MyExt.DoSomething(p)`. It's not putting this method into class Product.

Comment: Just a note - the access modifier "internal" is not a restriction at the namespace level but at the assembly level. see :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx. Yoou could also just put the static factory method in the Product class itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dotnet core you can do the following without even having to fiddle with any reflection:

```
YourCustomObject player = (YourCustomObject)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourCustomObject),true);
```

Activator is just in the System namespace.

Comment: Works, but only for parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 0):

if a class has only private and no public constructors, it can only be only accessible from nested classes within this class. what is worthy taking into consideration is the fact that classes with private default constructor cannot be derived.
so it only makes sense to declare constructor or constructors as private (in a class which has no public instructors) when the instances from the class are aimed to be created only within nested classes inside this class. there is no other valid places for instancing this class.

Comment: Classes with private default constructors can be derived, to inherit you must provide at least one protected or public constructor.

Comment: If you could add some clarity to this it would be more beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

You can instantiate instances of that type via reflection.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class demo
{
   private demo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is no parameter private constructor");
    }
    public demo(int a)
    {
        demo d = new demo('c');// u can call both private contstructors from here
        demo dd = new demo();
        Console.WriteLine("This is one parameter public constructor");
    }
    private demo(char a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is one parameter public constructor::" + a);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        demo obj = new demo(7);
        // demo obj = new demo();  // it will raise error
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment your solution

Answer (score -2):

The method Bobby is still in a different class, called Fred. That is why you can't access the prive constructor of the Bob class. What you are trying to do is not possible with attached methods. Even if they can be attached on another class they are still declared outside that class and follow the usual scope/access rules.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I included `Bobby` to show what I have done so that nobody wastes their time suggesting extension methods.