# Create instance of OperationAbortedException

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, exception

How I can to create OperationAbortedException? This code does not work:

```
var ex = new OperationAbortedException("Cannot update event comment");
```

ERROR: Cannot access private constructor 'OperationAbortedException'.

Comment: "does not work" means...? You get an error? Your computer explodes? You get a StackOverflowException instead?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the [`System.Data.OperationAbortedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.operationabortedexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then no, you can not construct an instance directly, there are no public consrtuctors.

If you really wanted to, you could use reflection with the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162776/accessing-a-private-constructor-from-outside-the-class-in-c-sharp), but I reccomend that you do not. It would be a corruption of the framework's design.

---

Here is the code you could use but, **please don't**.

```
var ctor = typeof(OperationAbortException).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, 
    new Type[0], 
    null);
var instance = (OperationAbortException)ctor.Invoke(null);
```

You'd have to work out which private constructor to use, if there is more than one, and which properties should be set to what. There is no garauntee that this behaviour would persist in later framework versions.

Answer (score 9):

The [`System.Data.OperationAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.operationabortedexception.aspx)-class (I'm assuming you mean this one, as you didn't fully qualify it in your question). has no public constructor and is `sealed`. These are strong hints that the framework designers didn't want you to use that exception for your own purposes. Presumably, because some inner workings of the framework would get confused if you did.

You should use a different exception for your purposes. From the message text you pass the following existing exceptions come to mind:

- [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx)
- [NotSupportException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx)

When selecting an existing exception from the .NET framework, make sure you not just select it by the name of the class alone. Make sure you read the respective MSDN page to understand the (original) intend for the exception. The respective documentation always starts with the words "The exception that is throw ...". If you find that text to match your intend, reuse the exception from the framework (or derive from it for finer control when eventually catching the exception).

Or create your own exception type, if you must.

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured it wasn't safe to use as well -- but trying to figure out what I should use instead.  I want to throw an exception if the user cancels a UI based operation -- there's `System.OperationCanceledException`, but that seems more geared towards CancellationTokens and async stuff (which I'm not doing).  Not sure what to do here to indicate that the user aborted the operation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. OperationAbortedException has a private constructor and an internal static method which calls that constructor. It is not possible to create a new OperationAbortedException from another assembly.