# create a dynamic class which overrides another class in C# / .Net

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I would like to not "allow" direct creations of objects in code like:

```
var p = new Product();
```

The reason is that I want this to be controlled by IOC, so I can easily change its implementation or extend it.  Hence, code would look something like:

```
var p = iocContainer.Get<Product>();
```

The issue is that one can "forget" to call the IOC, and instead `new` the Product.  My idea was to make `Product` an `abstract` class.  Then, dynamically create a type say `ProductImpl` which extends from `Product`, which is not abstract.  On application startup, all data objects are scanned and these dynamic classes are automatically created.  Is this possible? Ideally, the namespace for this type would be always the same, say `BusinessLogic.Impl.ProductImpl`.

The created dynamic class would be similar to the below:

```
public class ProductImpl : Product  
{
      public ProductImpl()
      {

      }

}
```

Comment: And how can I actually create it when I need it?  Plus I use RavenDB (document database) as my datastore, and I dont think it can re-create objects with private constructors when loading back from datastore.  However, I will look into this.

Comment: it works, both by code by using reflection and RavenDB supports it as well! :) thanks for your quick answer.  If you post this as an answer, I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of abstract classes, use private constructors.

Many IoC containers support this (or can be extended to). Also, `Activator.CreateInstance` has overloads that allow creating objects with non-public constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally with IOC you should be using interfaces rather than concrete objects. The IOC container then creates the appropriate object when an interface implementation is required.

Pass around `IProduct` interfaces instead. The IOC can the call the implementing object whatever it wants if you're worried about people newing it up. You could even put them in a separate assembly with internal constructors if you were really worried.

Comment: Actually I will not be using directly IOC, that is just to make it simpler.  I will get a `IDataObjectFactory` via IOC, which that in turn can create any object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the constructor(s) private and instantiate the class via reflection (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162797/148357)).
Alternatively, you can implement the pattern you described by using an interface and its implementation - I think it's better than using an abstract class

```
public interface IProduct {...}
public class ProductImpl : IProduct {...}
```

then using IoC you instantiate the implementation class, but return the interface. In this case the downside is that you have to remember to always use the interface and not the class.

Also, I think that depending on which IoC framework you are using, it's possible to instantiate classes with private constructors.

### UPDATE

A more elegant solution is to move the implementation class to a separate project in your solution, and declare the constructor as `internal`. I used this approach in a project, with Unity as IoC framework. I described its architecture in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20292336/148357) I posted a couple months ago, along with some code that you can readapt and use for your case.